# Google Drive folder name on Mac

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-folder

I'm using GoogleDrive on Mac with latest versions of GoogleDrive for Desktop (63.0.5.0) and macOS (12.6)

The root of my GoogleDrive folder that shows up in my Finder used to be named:

> My Drive

However it is now named:

> My Drive (myusername@gmail.com)

What would cause the name to be changed?
How can I get it to revert back to:

> My Drive

And a rhetorical question: Why doesn't Google name the folder "Google Drive" ?!